# Least degree polynomial with integer coefficient and having one root $\sqrt{8+\sqrt 6 +4\sqrt 3+ 3\sqrt 2}$

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Find Least degree polynomial with integer coefficient and having one root as $\sqrt{8+\sqrt 6 +4\sqrt 3+ 3\sqrt 2}$

I tried doing square again and again is there any simpler method

Comment: $ x^8 - 32 x^6 + 240 x^4 - 320 x^2 - 368 $ according to Wolframalpha

Comment: The unpleasant fact is that such polynomial factors over any finite field, since at least one number among $2,3,6$ is a quadratic residue $\pmod{p}$, so we cannot conclude the irreducibility of such polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ from the irreducibility over a finite field.

Comment: Yes I got same just by doing squaring. Now how to prove it is minimal such polynomial?

Comment: @Makar: you already have a solution below. The polynomial $x^4-32 x^3+240 x^2-320 x-368$ is irreducible since $b_{00},b_{01},b_{10},b_{11}$ provided by dan_fulea are algebraic conjugates over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us ask a computer algebra system, [sage](http://www.sagemath.org), about this:

```
sage: a = sqrt(8+sqrt(6)+4*sqrt(3)+3*sqrt(2))
sage: a.minpoly()
x^8 - 32*x^6 + 240*x^4 - 320*x^2 - 368
```

So the "blind result" is telling us that we have to "square three times". The first squaring is simple, so let us consider $b={8+\sqrt 6 +4\sqrt 3+ 3\sqrt 2}$ instead of the above $a=\sqrt{8+\sqrt 6 +4\sqrt 3+ 3\sqrt 2}$. Then a possibility to do the job as a human is to consider the Galois conjugates of $b$, working in the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 3)$ where $b$ lives in:
$$
\begin{aligned}
b=b_{00} &=8+\sqrt 6 +4\sqrt 3+ 3\sqrt 2\ ,\\
b_{10} &=8-\sqrt 6 +4\sqrt 3- 3\sqrt 2\ ,\\
b_{01} &=8-\sqrt 6 -4\sqrt 3+ 3\sqrt 2\ ,\\
b_{11} &=8+\sqrt 6 -4\sqrt 3- 3\sqrt 2\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and building the polynomial $(X-b_{00})(X-b_{10})(X-b_{01})(X-b_{11})$. Now it is easy to see the coefficient in $X^3$, which is $-\sum b_{jk}=-(8+8+8+8)=-32$. The free coefficient can by also computed in a few lines,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&b_{00}b_{10}b_{01}b_{11}
\\
&\qquad=(b_{00}b_{10})\cdot(b_{01}b_{11})
\\
&\qquad=
\Big(\ (8+4\sqrt 3)^2 - (\sqrt 6 + 3\sqrt 2)^2\ )
\Big(\ (8-4\sqrt 3)^2 - (\sqrt 6 - 3\sqrt 2)^2\ )
\\
&\qquad=
\Big(\ (112+64\sqrt 3) - (24+12\sqrt 3)\ )
\Big(\ (112-64\sqrt 3) - (24-12\sqrt 3)\ )
\\
&\qquad=
\Big(\ 88+52\sqrt 3\ )
\Big(\ 88-52\sqrt 3\ )
\\
&\qquad=-368\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Yes, we have a match of the free coefficient.

Let us do the job also for the coefficient of $X^2$ in the minimal polynomial of $b$, it is
$$
\begin{aligned}
&b_{00}b_{10}+(b_{00}+b_{10})\cdot(b_{01}+b_{11})+b_{01}b_{11}
\\
&\qquad= 
(88+52\sqrt 3)+2(8+4\sqrt 3)\cdot 2(8+4\sqrt 3)+(88-52\sqrt 3)
\\
&\qquad= 
88+88+4(64-48)
\\
&\qquad= 240
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The last coefficient can be computed along the same lines, grouping
$b_{00}b_{10}\cdot(b_{01}+b_{11})+
(b_{00}+b_{10})\cdot b_{01}b_{11}$, and the half of the computations are already done.

**Note:**
The indices $jk$ have the meaning
$$
b_{jk}=
8 + (-1)^j 3\sqrt 2 +(-1)^k 4\sqrt 3+ (-1)^j \sqrt 2\cdot (-1)^k \sqrt 3
\ ,
$$
corresponding to the Galois automorphism sending $\sqrt 2\to(-1)^j\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3\to(-1)^k \sqrt 3$.